# C# Automatically includes namespace (xs:) in type names (-> invalid xsd)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I am creating a Xsd file with C#. Which works really good.
Inside the Xml schema I define my own simple type but the following is happening:

Expected:

```
<xs:element name="name2" type="str32" />
```

Actual:

```
<xs:element name="name2" type="xs:str32" />
```

As you can see it includes 'xs:' where I define the type. When I remove the xs: then the Xsd is valid.

Here is my simple type definition:

```
<xs:simpleType name="str32">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="32" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Last but not least here is the C# code:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/fud0xown8nzauyx/DbToXsdConverter.cs

In conclusion: I want to remove the xs: in front of the type name but it is automatically beeing added. I do not want to remove the namespace everywhere, just in this type name.

EDIT:
Here is the code which writes the Xml Schema to a file:

```
public class XsdWriter
{
    public static void saveFile(String file, XmlSchema schema)
    {
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = CreateWriter(file))
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = CreateNamespaceManager();

        schema.Write(writer, namespaceManager);
    }

    //TODO
    String tempFile = "temp_" + file;

    File.Delete(tempFile);
    File.Move(file, tempFile);

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tempFile))
    {
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            String line = "";

            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Replace("type=\"xs:str", "type=\"str");

                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }

    File.Delete(tempFile);
}

private static XmlTextWriter CreateWriter(String file)
{
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(file, new UTF8Encoding());
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    return writer;
}

private static XmlNamespaceManager CreateNamespaceManager()
{
    XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

    return namespaceManager;
}
```

}

EDIT: SOLVED, I needed to remove the namespace from the XmlQualifiedName when using a simple custom type.

Comment: You can't expect us to examine your whole file, you should paste in the code that writes the value.

Comment: I am sorry, edited the post and appended the code. The stuff after "TODO" is to remove the xs: in the type name manually.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I needed to remove the namespace from the XmlQualifiedName when using a simple custom type.